# Terraform submodule outputs?

Tags: terraform

I'm having some issues getting my Terraform outputs correct since I'm sub-submoduled (?),
I would think that I could pretty close to copy paste the module output from my plan in
order to get my `outputs.tf` working. Here below I am looking to ge the address ID of my
db instance..

```
Terraform will perform the following actions:

  + module.db.module.db_instance.aws_db_instance.this
      id:                                  <computed>
      address:                             <computed>
      allocated_storage:                   "5"
```

I would think that I should then be able to write my output as follows

```
output "this_db_instance_address" {
  description = "The address of the RDS instance"
  value       = "${module.db.db_instance.aws_db_instance.address}"
}

....

Initializing modules...
- module.db
- module.db.db_subnet_group
- module.db.db_parameter_group
- module.db.db_option_group
- module.db.db_instance

Error: output 'this_db_instance_address': "module.db_instance.aws_db_instance.this.address" is not a valid output for module "db"
```

Not really sure where to go form here? Happy to update with whatever other information is needed to unblock me.

Comment: How do the outputs of your submodule look like? How many levels of nesting do you have?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd take a look at the link below, it seems very similar to your issue. This article also links to a similar issue. Unfortunately they're both still open.

[output from submodule does not get propagated #16232](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/16232)

Answer (score 2):

In case anyone finds this, with a child mod which has outputs which reference submodule resource outputs you output them (at least with 0.14) like this.  For a submodule called `bastion`:

```
output "child_bastion_public_dns" {
  value = module.bastion.bastion_public_dns
}

output "child_bastion_public_ip" {
  value = module.bastion.bastion_public_ip
}
```

you can then reference these as normal in a root module called `root_mod` with this form, assuming you define a root module which calls the child module whose outputs are above:

```
output "root_mod_bastion_public_dns" {
  value = module.root_mod.bastion_public_dns
}

output "bastion_public_ip" {
  value = module.root_mod.bastion_public_ip
}
```